# How do I add an animate a function that's within a hover handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate, raphael

I have a an animation of a piechart using Raphael. For each segment, I'm adding a hover function, so that brief description of each segment appears on the bottom. I can't figure out how to get the description to fade in. Difficult to explain here, but you can see my code at

http://jsfiddle.net/WJMaU/1/ Read my comments to see what I'm talking about.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It appears to be fading in for me. What's the issue?

Comment: Same here. It's fading in and fading out nicely.

Comment: While I managed to get the rectangle to fade in and out, I haven't been able to get the text to fade in, although it does fade out. When I apply the same method I used for the rectangle to the text, I get returned values of "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having a mistake there:

```
this.label.animate({opacity:0},0);
```

Why 0 and not 400 like the rest. With 400 works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/vvKtU/2/